# jquery target all objects of a certain type

Tags: jquery

I'm not the greatest at jquery, but basically what I am trying to do is modify a bootstrap datetimepicker so that when the date is clicked the menu closes.  The code below will work for individual pickers, but I have tons of these things so I basically want to make it a permanent thing.

```
var el = $('#start_date').datetimepicker({
    pickTime:false
});

el.on('changeDate',function(){
    $('.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget').slideUp('fast');
    });
```

So basically I want to remove the need for the var el = declaration and target all datetimepickers.

I attempted to give them all a class and for some reason that doesn't seem to work

```
$('.change_date').on('changeDate',function(){
    $('.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget').slideUp('fast');
    });
```

I don't really know why it would see the selector differently than the variable assignment, but it seems to.

Comment: Give them all a common class or attribute you can select.

Comment: If they have a similar ID, you can use `$('[id*=similarPart]')`

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry for confusing the datepicker ... how about having a class for all of them and doing the following:

```
$(".myclass").data('datetimepicker').on("changeDage", function(e) {
 // do something
});
```

Comment: I'm not using that one I'm using [this](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

assuming each of the datetimepicker has a class of datetime for example, and the menu has a class of datetimemenu, the following would do what you are asking for:-

$(".datetime").on("click", function() { $(".datetimemenu").hide(); } );